# useEffect Hook not running on render in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, react-hooks

I've tried to get the useEffect in this functional component to work so many different ways but it never triggers. It's supposed to grab a document from a Firebase Cloud Firestore and render the text on the page, but no luck so far.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RootLayout from "@/app/layout";
import { db } from "@/app/context/firebase";
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Post() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const [post, setPost] = useState("");
  const docRef = doc(db, "posts", id);

  const docGetter = async () => {
    // Snore doesn't appear in console
    console.log("snore");
    // docRef does appear when console logging, but no idea if this 
    // docSnap works
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    console.log(docSnap?.exists());
    if (docSnap?.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", docSnap?.data());
      setPost(docSnap?.data().text);
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Purple doesn't appear in the console
    console.log("purple");
    docGetter();
  }, []);

  return post ? (
    <RootLayout>
      <div>{post}</div>
    </RootLayout>
  ) : (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  );
}
```

Basically, you click a card on the homepage, and it's supposed to take you to a page that shows the article, which it fetches from Firebase using the id passed along in the router query.

Even if I remove the async function from the useEffect and just try to get it to put "purple" in the console, it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: `docGetter` should be inside the `useEffect` (my preference when possible) or listed as a dependency. Depending on the function's final form, you might get an infinite loop if it's listed as a dependency. If that's the case, you must wrap `docGetter` in a `useCallback`.

Comment: Are you sure this component is being rendered at all? If you add a log outside of `useEffect` do you see anything there? If not, check the parent component to see if it's actually rendering it.

Comment: I've tried putting docGetter in the useEffect with no luck , maybe I'll try a useCallback. 

The component is being rendered, I've logged outside of the useEffect and I always get whatever I'm looking for there, but no such luck on the useEffect logging things